# Switch statement when using a string variable for the list of alternatives does not compile

Tags: r

I have read the `switch` documentation and I am wondering if it is possible to use a string variable for the list of alternatives (...) in `switch` instead of using the literal string ("mean", "median", "trimmed"). Let's clarify it using the same [example](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/switch.html) from de `switch` documentation, but adding a variable of type list for taking the literals for the list of alternatives:

```
require(stats)
centre <- function(x, type) {
    sit <- list(mean = "mean", median = "median", trimmed = "trimmed")
    switch(type,
         sit$mean = mean(x),
         sit$median = median(x),
         sit$trimmed = mean(x, trim = .1))
}
x <- rcauchy(10)
centre(x, "mean")
centre(x, "median")
centre(x, "trimmed")
```

but adding the `sit` variable for taking all possible cases. It does not compile. I get the following error:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"    switch(type,
         sit$mean ="
Error: unexpected ',' in "         sit$median = median(x),"
Error: unexpected ')' in "         sit$trimmed = mean(x, trim = .1))"
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
Error: could not find function "centre"
Error: could not find function "centre"
Error: could not find function "centre"
```

Probably the `switch` statement is not intended for that or I am missing something. My intention is to avoid misspelling with the possible alternatives, because my real `switch` has more than 10 alternatives.

It also does not work when using:

```
sit <- names(list(mean = "mean", median = "median", trimmed = "trimmed"))
    switch(type,
         sit[1] = mean(x),
         sit[2] = median(x),
         sit[3] = mean(x, trim = .1))
```

and to create a `switch` statement using and array does not work either:

```
listNames <- names(list(mean = "mean", median = "median", trimmed = "trimmed"))
print(switch(2, listNames))
NULL
```

but, it works for the situation when the `EXPR` argument from `switch` is an integer:

```
print(switch(2, listNames[1], listNames[2], listNames[3]))
[1] "median"
```

Comment: I think this has to do with the fact that R won't let you use functions for argument names. Like this example `df <- data.frame(temp="a")` then try `data.frame(df$temp="a")` or `data.frame(df[["temp"]="a")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be trying to dynamically name parameters. This isn't possible with simple function calls. If you run

```
f(a=b)
```

`a` is never evaluated to a value. It is interpreted as a symbol which is matched up to a parameter name. You cannot place a variable that you expect to be evaluated to return a value on the left of an equals sign. That's just how the language works.

You are trying to use switch with a character value so it needs to use the names of the named parameter to evaluate the switch. (No names are required when using a numeric value).

It's somewhat unclear to me exactly what you are trying to do and I don't actually see a specific question in your post, but I don't think there's really a need to use `switch()` here at all.

For example

```
require(stats)
centre <- function(x, type) {
    sit <- list(
       mean = mean, 
       median = median, 
       trimmed = function(x) mean(x, trim=.1)
    )
    if (type %in% names(sit)) {
        sit[[type]](x)
    } else {
        stop(paste("Unrecognized type:", type))
    }
}
x <- rcauchy(10)
centre(x, "mean")
centre(x, "median")
centre(x, "trimmed")
centre(x, "other")
```

Comment: it is just a toy example for illustrating this possible limitation of the `switch` statement. I prefer to use `switch` instead of `if-else` block but unfortunately in this case there no other option.

Comment: You could dynamically build a call to switch() with do.call() but that seems like overkill.

Answer (score 1):

There are potential problems with using `with` in programming but in this case it appears fairly safe:

```
centre <- function(x, type) {
    sit <- list(mean = "mean", median = "median", trimmed = "trimmed")
    with( sit, switch(type,
         mean = mean(x),
         median = median(x),
         trimmed = mean(x, trim = .1)))
}

> x <- rcauchy(10)
> centre(x, "mean")
[1] 0.6333933
> centre(x, "median")
[1] 0.2223546
> centre(x, "trimmed")
[1] 0.5122541
```